# Opencv VideoCapture() for Raspberry Pi cam working with Python 3.6 but not with Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi, computer-vision

I am writing a little Python script in which I want to use OpenCV to capture images from my Raspberry Pi camera.  I am initializing video capturing with the following line.

`cam=cv2.VideoCapture("nvarguscamerasrc ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=(int)1640, height=(int)1232,format=(string)NV12, framerate=(fraction)30/1 ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR ! appsink")`

I am using a Jetson Nano, so I was using the default Python 3.6 version at the start, but since I needed a package that only works with >=3.7 I installed Python 3.7 and adjusted the shebang line to `#!/usr/bin/env python3.7`

Before that I was working just fine, but after I switched Python version it doesn't work anymore.

I don't really get an error message, only the returned value of `cam.read()` is `False`, so I can't grab a frame from the camera.

The important part of the script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7 //if this says Python 3.6 it is working fine.

import cv2
import sys
import argparse
import os

from pathlib import Path
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def main():

    cam=cv2.VideoCapture("nvarguscamerasrc ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=(int)1640, height=(int)1232,format=(string)NV12, framerate=(fraction)30/1 ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR ! appsink")

    # ret is True with python 3.6 and False with 3.7
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    if not ret:
        print("Failed to grab initial frame. Fix camera!")
        sys.exit()

    cv2.imshow("test", frame)
```

I am using OpenCV version 4.9.0.80.

Comment: Third-party libraries must be installed separately for each Python installation where they will be used. Please see the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: I know that but that is not the problem. I do not get an import error or anything. I even created a new virtual environment with python 3.7 as default and freshly installed opencv-python package with pip.

Comment: Then you will need to explain, at an absolute minimum, what "doesn't work" actually means. Please read [ask] and [mre].

Comment: I said, that cam.read() returns false. cv2.VideoCapture() doesnt throw an exception or any error message, when it doesnt find a valid camera. Some people might know what could be the problem with the different python versions and opencv or how to better check for what went wrong. That is why im asking the question. You linked me to a question that is completely unrelated to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture("nvarguscamerasrc ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=(int)1640, height=(int)1232,format=(string)NV12, framerate=(fraction)30/1 ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR ! appsink")
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(cam, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. I get this error: `cv2.error: OpenCV(4.9.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'VideoCapture'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't convert object to 'str' for 'filename'
>  - VideoCapture() missing required argument 'params' (pos 3)
>  - Argument 'index' is required to be an integer
>  - VideoCapture() missing required argument 'params' (pos 3)`

Comment: You should put pipeline pamameter in VideoCapture(cam)